# Can't return view from controller when creating a list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is a simplified version of the problem I'm having. Basically, Visual Studio won't let me create an object (like a list) inside of my controller.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace HDDTest0818.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            public List<string> someList = new List<string>();

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the errors I'm getting:

`Index` - `HomeController.Index();: not all code paths return a value`

The third open brace - `} expected`

`return` - `Invalid token 'return' in class, struct, or interface member declaration`

`View` - `'HomeController.View' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial`

`View` - `'HomeController.View' hides inherited member 'Controller.View'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended`

`View` - `Method must have a return type`

The last closing curly brace - `Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected`

Comment: These are all compile time errors, you have invalid c# code.

Comment: `public List<string> someList = new List<string>();` -> `List<string> someList = new List<string>();`

Comment: Ah, thank you Ant P! That worked! Why can't it be public though?

Comment: Because it's a local variable inside a method - not a class-level field. Using `public` there doesn't make sense.

Comment: you don't need `public` before creating your List variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to revise your code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace HDDTest0818.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //here is where you would declare your List variable public so that scope of this variable can be within the entire class...
       // public List<string> someList = new List<string>();
        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            /*public*/ List<string> someList = new List<string>(); 
            //you need to get rid of public before you create your List variable
            // if you want to declare this list variable as public you need to do it outside of the method (Index())..

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps!